# Cast timestamp column as timeuuid

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Want to convert `timestamp` column in `timeuuid`, here's my `spark` data frame (imported csv file from `cassandra`):

```
scala> newDF.printSchema
root
 |-- eventID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sessionID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fullJson: string (nullable = true)
```

I was able to create new column `event_date` by simply casting new column to `DateType`:

```
val finalDF = newDF.withColumn("event_date", helpFrame("timestamp").cast(DateType))
```

Is there any way to convert `timestamp` column to `timeuuid` using `com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs`.

In my other (`Java`) app I managed to do it like:

```
Date date = new Date();
UUID uuid2 = new UUID(UUIDs.startOf(date.getTime()).getMostSignificantBits(), random.nextLong());
```

Wondering how can it be simply done in `Spark shell`

Comment: In spark-shell can be done with UDF: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html

Comment: val timeUUID = udf(() => UUIDs.timeBased().toString)
val uuid1 = finalDF.withColumn("timeuuid", timeUUID($"timestamp"))
java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.<init>(ScalaUDF.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.apply(UserDefinedFunction.scala:71)
  ... 79 elided

Comment: SparkSQL does not support custom types. Any reason why you need this UUID object within your spark application? Basically you either need to avoid using this type or use RDDs or datasets (and not dataframes).

Comment: It's because I'm reimporting Cassandra table and switching timestamp with timeuuid.

Comment: what about using an intermediate type such as `string`? You process it as string and when need it you convert to timeuuid. Is there any Spark based distributed processing you need to do with timeuuids?

Comment: i put data from kafka to cassandra (timeuuid) and to elasticsearch (timestamp), but cause of table architecture, it has to be timeuuid.. dont know much about uiids, but is it possible to convert it to timestamp form if it’s from string and not timestamp?